# Responsive Website (Link Rel / Media Queries / Load Css and Html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Nice to meet you all! I´m Mauro Cordeiro from Brazil, and I´m starting to learn coding, and following lots of tutorials. I love Stack Overflow! Learn a lot with you guys!

In fact i´m a Musician and Character Animator, and I´m working and finishing my Band´s Official Website! It´s called LeatherJacks, but i´m loving to code too! =)

My doubt is about media queries and loading contents.

I´m building my Responsive Website and I have this "Link Rel" code at the start of my Desktop Html code, as shown below:

```
<!--THE MAIN WEBSITE --> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="M:\00_LEATHERJACKS - 2017\06_WEBSITE\01 - LeatherJacks - Website 2017\01_css\01_Responsive_1920px.css">




<!-- META TAGS FOR DIFFERENT RESOLUTIONS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 1368px)" href="M:\00_LEATHERJACKS - 2017\06_WEBSITE\01 - LeatherJacks - Website 2017\01_css\02_Responsive_1368px.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 1000px)" href="M:\00_LEATHERJACKS - 2017\06_WEBSITE\01 - LeatherJacks - Website 2017\01_css\03_Responsive_1000px.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 816px)" href="M:\00_LEATHERJACKS - 2017\06_WEBSITE\01 - LeatherJacks - Website 2017\01_css\04_Responsive_MOBILE.css">
```

But in fact, when I redimension my browser to 816px, it loads only the css style, but not the another html file (I mean: the html coding I did for mobile resolution, with contains less div´s and stuff).

How do I load both Html and CSS at my main html code, guys? 
What´s the best way to do it?

I tried a jquery If / Else conditional, using "Location", but it didn´t work.

What I need is a page that works and chande Everything (Both css and html) when reduced to that 816px width or less.

The another resolutions (1920px, 1368px and 1000px) works and fits as gloves haha! Working with percent values it´s a Bless hahaah!

Anyway, thank you so much, guys!

Any help will be precious for me to finish and publish my page!

Let´s Rock!

Mauro.

Comment: I would approach it like this.. I will put the html code in one page.. then use jquery for resize.. then display none for that html code and display block for another one.. then for the css I will use media queries..

Comment: How do I do that, Shadow Fiend? Loved that idea!

Comment: look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/c864sak7/).. this is basically the idea..

Comment: wowwwwwwwwwwwwww!!! I´m going to try it!

Comment: MAAAAAAAAAAAAANNNNN thank you so much! You Saved my life! =)

Comment: But I think I will have to re-edit some css stuff now... he changed a little some of my div´s positions... Dunno why, but I think it will be easy to fix! =)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

**Example:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 816px) and (max-width: 1000px)' href="04_Responsive_MOBILE.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 1368x)' href="03_Responsive_1000px.css"/>
```

You could also have all of the media queries in one file as well:

**Example:**

[image]

Also i would highly suggest you have the folder structure **without the spaces**.

> The space character is unsafe because significant spaces may disappear
>   and insignificant spaces may be introduced when URLs are transcribed
>   or typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-processing programs

And i would suggest you should use **relative paths**:

**Relative Paths**
(source: [Quick Reminder About File Paths](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/))

> - Is the image in the same directory as the file referencing it?
> - Is the image in a directory **below**?
> - Is the image in a directory **above**?
>
> By "below" and "above", I mean subdirectories and parent directories.
>   Relative file paths give us a way to travel in both directions. Take a
>   look at my primitive example: [image]
>
> Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:
>
> - Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
> - Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
> - Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts    there (and so on...)
> - To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep    moving forward

**Including HTML within another HTML**

***With pure Javascript:***

HTML

```
<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div>
```

JS

```
<script>
w3.includeHTML();
</script>
```

***With jQuery:***

HTML

```
<div id="includedContent"></div>
```

JS

```
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#includedContent").load("content.html"); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, Hash! I´m starting to understand more about directories... It´s stille a little confusing to me, but i´m starting getting more and more comfortable with them!

I did your Link Rel suggestion, took off the spaces, and everything worked... But as I said previously, my website loads only the css styles...

I need to make my browser also load my "Mobile Alternative Version.html" when max-width gets equal or minor than 816px, you know? Could you help me on this one also?

Thank you so much! =)

Comment: Is there a way I can tell my "Main.html" file (maybe via <meta> tag) to load both the "mobile.html" and it´s respective "mobile.css" styles and codes?

Comment: if load as in mean include i have added the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, Hash... But it still didn´t work =( 

I mean... where do I put the variables to load my alternative mobile site, at the max-width=816px?

Would be something like

div "includedContent" with link rel max width 816px  inside, then the java script after?

Comment: Or do I put all the new css style coding at the included content div as a style?

Comment: @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)

Comment: you can have a query like that

Comment: im confused now. you should have the mobile styles in a media query. if it detects its mobile only those styles will be used